# Irreducible polynomial equations from equations of algebraic functions in two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irreducible-polynomials

Let $A$ be an arbitrary algebraic function in dependence of the two variables $x$ and $y$.
Let's consider the equation $A(x,y)=0$ (equation 1) involving $x$ and $y$. For which kinds of equation 1 can we decide if there is an **irreducible** polynomial equation whose solution set contains the solution set of equation (1)?

I already know that we can multiply both sides of the equation by the denominators of both sides to get an equivalent or non-equivalent equation. And the solution set of this new equation does contain the equivalent solution set. At least in the one-variable case, the equivalent solution set yields an equivalent polynomial equation.

I also see: We can first separate the denominators and the irreducible factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a simple first case of corresponding radical equations.

Let
$A_0\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y]$ algebraic,
$P\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[t]\setminus\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$,
$P_1\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y]\setminus(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x]\cup\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[y])$,
$r\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$
so that $P((P_1(x,y))^r)$ and $A_0(x,y)$ are coprime,
and let $P^{-1}$ denote a suitable partial inverse of $P$.

$$\frac{P((P_1(x,y))^r)}{A_0(x,y)}=0$$

$$P((P_1(x,y))^r)=0$$

$$(P_1(x,y))^r=P^{-1}(0)$$

$$P_1(x,y)=(P^{-1}(0))^\frac{1}{r}$$

$$P_1(x,y)-(P^{-1}(0))^\frac{1}{r}=0$$

The equation is irreducible if $P$ is irreducible and $P_1(x,y)-(P^{-1}(0))^\frac{1}{r}$ is irreducible for all suitable partial inverses $P^{-1}$.